# How to store a password when you need the actual password text

Tags: php, security, passwords, md5, imap

My database stores user's login passwords in MD5, so when they login it compares their typed in password converted to MD5 vs the MD5 password in the database.

I'm implementing functionality where the application can connect to their email account using IMAP. So I need to store the user's email account password in the database, but as far as I'm aware I can't use MD5 because I need to actually end up with their password as plain text to use to connect via an IMAP connection.

What would be a solution to store their password securely in the database, but be able to retrieve it and convert it into plain text in a script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, MD5 is not a secure way to store passwords. Take a look at the [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function and **bcrypt** for a more modern and secure solution. See also: [How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php)

As for the IMAP password, you do **not** need hashing as those are "one-way". You need an encryption algorithm.

One of the better options is to use `openssl_encrypt()` and a secure key stored on the server. This is the approach Laravel takes for example.

Take a look at this as an example: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php#L62

```
/**
 * Encrypt the given value.
 *
 * @param  string  $value
 * @return string
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\EncryptException
 */
public function encrypt($value)
{
    $iv = random_bytes($this->getIvSize());
    $value = \openssl_encrypt(serialize($value), $this->cipher, $this->key, 0, $iv);
    if ($value === false) {
        throw new EncryptException('Could not encrypt the data.');
    }
    // Once we have the encrypted value we will go ahead base64_encode the input
    // vector and create the MAC for the encrypted value so we can verify its
    // authenticity. Then, we'll JSON encode the data in a "payload" array.
    $mac = $this->hash($iv = base64_encode($iv), $value);
    $json = json_encode(compact('iv', 'value', 'mac'));
    if (! is_string($json)) {
        throw new EncryptException('Could not encrypt the data.');
    }
    return base64_encode($json);
}
/**
 * Decrypt the given value.
 *
 * @param  string  $payload
 * @return string
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException
 */
public function decrypt($payload)
{
    $payload = $this->getJsonPayload($payload);
    $iv = base64_decode($payload['iv']);
    $decrypted = \openssl_decrypt($payload['value'], $this->cipher, $this->key, 0, $iv);
    if ($decrypted === false) {
        throw new DecryptException('Could not decrypt the data.');
    }
    return unserialize($decrypted);
}
/**
 * Get the IV size for the cipher.
 *
 * @return int
 */
protected function getIvSize()
{
    return 16;
}
```

Obviously, that Laravel code relies on other parts of Laravel, but as an example, this is sufficient. Once you have the encrypted value, you can store it in your database.

Remember security is only as strong as the weakest link -- so make sure your database credentials are secure and your database user has the minimum amount of permissions for your application to function.

Comment: Why create a mac of the encryption when it is not checked during decryption?

Comment: @zaph that is a good question. Not sure what Taylor's though process was was this.

Comment: It is your answer and therefore your code. When one copies code it is then theirs, one can not, having chosen the code, turn around and place blame elsewhere. Further there should be attribution other than a "Take a look at this as an example" with no mention that the following code was copied.

Comment: It is standard SO practice to copy the code over from a link in case the link dies. Had I not, then there would be complaints to not just leave a link. I have opted for answer preservation.

Comment: It is hardly a good answer when providing code you do not understand such as why there is an unused mac.